# Android: dialog box with android profile picture

Tags: android, facebook

I have a custom dialog box where I am trying to load the dialog box with face book profile image and name below is my code

```
public void postToWall(String message) {
    String fbUser="";

    try {
        JSONObject me = new JSONObject(facebook.request("me"));
        String id=me.getString("id");

        ImageView picture;
        fbUser = me.getString("name");
        TextView usr = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        picture = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView4);
        URL image_value= new URL("http://graph.facebook.com/" + fbUser + "/picture" );
        Bitmap profPict=BitmapFactory.decodeStream(image_value.openConnection().getInputStream());
        picture.setImageBitmap(profPict);
        usr.setText(fbUser);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } 
}
```

instead of fb feed dialog I created custom dialog ,while posting I want the  user image and name in the dialog box , the code seems ok for me but don't know where I am going wrong.
any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the problem solved ..doing wrong at this line 
URL image_value= new URL("http://graph.facebook.com/" + id+ "/picture" ); previously i used username instead of id in url...